# Java to Kotlin auto converter: How to automatically convert Streams to Kotlin functions?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Using IntelliJ IDEA, I can automatically convert some Java code to Kotlin code. However, when Java code uses things like `Stream`, it only converts to Kotlin grammar, but it still uses Stream. But we know Kotlin's sequences/collections API is much, much simpler than Java's Stream API, so I would appreciate it if I could automatically convert Stream to Kotlin's API.

For example,

```
myList.stream().map(x -> x + 1).collect(Collectors.toList()); // java
```

How to auto convert to:

```
myList.map { it + 1 } // kotlin
```

(notice the `.map` here works on the Iterable, and there is no `stream()` and `collect()` anymore).

Comment: IDEA doesn't have a feature like this. I suppose there could already be a plugin for this out there. The plugin would have to be quite sophisticated to be able to reliably make a good decision between converting stream code to direct manipulation vs. a sequence.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks. I do hope there exist a plugin, but cannot find yet :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is the feature request for that in Kotlin plugin bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-14393

Feel free to vote and follow.

Comment: Thanks, I vote for it