# How to let Java-to-Kotlin converter understand Lombok and convert to data class?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

For example, a Java lombok class and its usage:

```
@Data
class Person {
  String name;
  Integer age;
}

new Person().setName("a").setAge(42);
```

I want to convert to Kotlin's data class automatically:

```
data class Person (
  val name: String,
  val age: Int,
)

Person(name="a", age=42)
```

However, Intellij IDEA's current automatic converter does not seem to do the job... Is there an approach to solve this?

P.S. This is a sibling of [Java to Kotlin auto converter: How to automatically convert Streams to kotlin functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813820/java-to-kotlin-auto-converter-how-to-automatically-convert-streams-to-kotlin-fu). I make this a separate question to avoid asking two not-that-related things in one question.

Comment: I don't think the Java-to-Kotlin converter's behaviour is customisable at all (?) Can you customise any of its other behaviours?

Comment: This would make a good feature request.

Comment: @Sweeper No I also cannot customize. But I hope there exist some plugins (?) or sth like that

Comment: @Todd Agree. Hope this feature exists!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an existing feature request regarding automatic conversion from @lombok.Data to data class https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-12602. Feel free to upvote/comment on it.

Comment: Thanks I voted for it